# Regex Structural Search Not Containing Word

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to search through my Android project's XML files for objects that do not contain a certain object.

My set of objects looks like this:

```
<View
 android:id="@+id/obstacle3"
 android:layout_width="@dimen/obstacle_width"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/obstacle_width"
 android:background="@drawable/play_portal"
 android:layout_below="@+id/obstacle36"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/obstacle29"
 ads:brother="@+id/obstacle21"
/>

<View
 android:id="@+id/obstacle3"
 android:layout_width="@dimen/obstacle_width"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/obstacle_width"
 android:background="@drawable/play_portal"
 android:layout_below="@+id/obstacle36"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/obstacle29"
/>

<View
 android:id="@+id/obstacle3"
 android:layout_width="@dimen/obstacle_width"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/obstacle_width"
 android:background="@drawable/play_portal"
 android:layout_below="@+id/obstacle36"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/obstacle29"
 ads:brother="@+id/obstacle21"
/>
```

With this search,
`<View(\s+[^>]*?)ads([^>]*?/>)` I can find all Views that **contain** `ads:brother` attribute, but I want the inverse; I want to find all Views that **do not contain** `ads:brother` attribute.

I've tried numerous things to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**__Insert mandatory disclaimer *"don't parse xml with regex"* here__**

```
<View([^>](?!ads))*?\/>
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/cF5vQ3/1)

The idea is to check that after each matched character there is no `ads` following, thus there is no `ads` in the entire match.

Comment: That pulls everything as well. I'm looking to only pull the <Views that DO NOT contain the ads:brother attribute